latex apa7 titlepage output missing running head, page number, author notes and abstract not on new page
I am using APA7 and the title page is NOT as prescribed by APA7

Running Head is missing
page number (1) is missing
author notes are missing/appear as footnotes
Abstract does not appear on a new page
text does not appear on a new page

I am obviously doing something wrong, but what?
I am using MacTex on a MacBook Pro
\documentclass[doc,12pt, a4paper]{apa7}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
 \usepackage{csquotes}
 \usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
 %\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
 
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{color,soul}
 \usepackage{enumitem}
 \usepackage{makecell}
 \usepackage[american]{varioref}
 

% the title commands 
\title{{\small{(working title)}}\\
Conceptual Change Towards Mathematics\\
{\large{- the difference between two methods of teaching -}}
}

\shorttitle{Develop Computational Thinking}

%\shorttitle{Computational Thinking}
\authorsnames{Flavia Surpol}
\authorsaffiliations{Master Educational Sciences Open University{,} The Netherlands}

\duedate{Aug-2025}

\authornote{
Student number: 1234675\\
E-mail address: student@university.com\\
Course code and name: X34 Mathematics\\
Supervisor: prof. Power\\
Number of words: 5600\\
Date: 01-02-2023
}


\abstract{Notes about two mathematics ways of teaching} 
    

% section numbering
\setcounter {secnumdepth}{4}

\definecolor{EMPTY}{RGB}{255,255,255}



%\addbibresource{../../b-bib/thesisPlan.bib}

%\includeonly{t-test}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction} 
Some text

%\include{section1}
%\include{section2}

%\printbibliography
\end{document}



You can use the man option to switch to a layout which seems to match your requirements more closely than doc:
\documentclass[man,12pt, a4paper]{apa7}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}


Yes, it works, must be that simple as I expected. But I keep wondering why apa7 document does not give details about types of documents and the way elements are printed.
